# How to update value in View Model without refreshing the whole page in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to reload the whole page only if database was updated. So I'm trying to get the number of records in the database every 5 seconds. However when I add or delete records in the database, the number of records displayed changes only if I refresh the whole page. 
Is it possible to get new value without refreshing the whole page?

---

Index.cshtml:

```
function refresh() {
        //location.reload();
        var jsObject = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.DataList));
        var numbOfRecords = jsObject.length;
        alert(numbOfRecords);
        setTimeout(refresh, 5000);
        }
        refresh();
```

simplified HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var db = new ElementsContext())
        {
            var query =
                from data in db.Data
                select new
                {
                    someData = data.DataElem
                };
            var allData = new List<Data>();

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                allData.Add(new Data()
                {
                    DataElem = item.someData
                });
            }
            var viewModel = new DataViewModel
            {
                DataList = allData
            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

Comment: Can you use Ajax?

Comment: go for ajax....

Comment: And don't call the server every 5 seconds. Use [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) or similar so you view is only updated when a record in the db changes